# Executing Swing Application based on Maven and Spring

Tags: java, spring, swing, maven

I have created a Maven based Swing Application included spring as well but I do not how to give this to anyone because I can't see any jar file there, Where people can click to execute a program and to show a JFrame.
Even if I try to build using NetBeans its creating only one jar file under the target folder but when I am clicking on it its doing nothing.

IDE Name: NetBeans 8
Java Version 1.7

Pasted POM.XML File and XmlConfig File for my Maven-Spring App and also added the error when I am trying to execute from CMD.

### POM File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.SQLDemo</groupId>
<artifactId>MOM-TQ</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
</project>
```

### XML Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="myBasicDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dbDriver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${dbUrl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${dbUsername}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dbPassword}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="src/main/java/com/mom/assets/dbinfo.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mom.tq"></context:component-scan>


<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="reTableClass" class="com.mom.tq.RETableClass" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="reTableDAO" class="com.mom.tq.RETableDAO" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="desktopFrame" class="com.mom.tq.DesktopFrame" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="internalFrame" class="com.mom.tq.InternalFrame"  scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="batchTableClass" class="com.mom.tq.BatchTableClass" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="batchTableDAO" class="com.mom.tq.BatchTableDAO" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="internalBatchForm" class="com.mom.tq.InternalBatchForm" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="internalDeleteTraineeForm" class="com.mom.tq.InternalDeleteTraineeForm" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="internalUpdateBatchForm" class="com.mom.tq.InternalUpdateBatchForm" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="internalUpdateTraineeForm" class="com.mom.tq.InternalUpdateTraineeForm" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="adminTableClass" class="com.mom.tq.AdminTableClass" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="adminTableDAO" class="com.mom.tq.AdminTableDAO" scope="prototype"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Share your pom.xml, may be you should create a fat jar with all the dependencies then run it with java -jar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `maven-assembly-plugin`. With this plugin you can create a single jar with all your dependencies, such way you can execute it. Also you have to define which is your main class, is to say, the class that has to be executed when clicking on your jar artifact.

Here you are with a sample of one develop i did:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>here.put.your.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: its still not working and giving the error "A JNI Error has occurred" Actually my application connecting with database as well using spring. I think because of that reason its not getting showing me the JFrame and if I check error it showing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sspringFramework/context/ApplicationContext

Comment: That class is part of `spring-context` dependency, so it must be inside packaged jar. When you run `mvn package` with this configuration, you get two packaged jars, one of them it is appended with '-jar-with-dependencies.jar'. Did you run your app with this package?

Comment: yes. So there are 2 jar files. 1 "MOM-TQ-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" and 2 "MOM-TQ-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar". If I execute first one using command prompt it gives msg "No Main Manifest Attribute". If I add Manifest file it gives error "A JNI Error has occured". If I try to execute  2nd jar it shows a JFrame but when I clicks on any button it gives the error " Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinationStoreException: IOException parsinng XML Document from class path resource [mypack/cmlConfigFile.xml];nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundExcep

Comment: This is the code which I am trying to execute  : ---->                                                         private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        
        appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mypack/xmlConfigFile.xml");
        InternalFrame frame = appContext.getBean("internalFrame", InternalFrame.class);
        desktopPane.add(frame);
        frame.show();
        ((FileSystemXmlApplicationContext)appContext).close();
    }

Comment: So as you states, when running the jar with dependencies you can start the application, although it comes later with an Exception. So you can click and execute your app, that was your question. Now the exception you have is telling you there is a configuration file (_it seems appContext for Spring_) `mypack/cmlConfigFile.xml` not found. Is this file inside jar package?